# Handling JMS-acknowledgements in Camel

Tags: java, apache-camel, jms

We are implementing a distributed system based (among others) upon JMS and REST calls. Currently we are looking at two components `A` and `B`. Component `A` reads from an a ActiveMQ-Queue (via Camel-`from`), processes the message and sends it on to `B` via REST (this is done via Camel `.to`/`.inOnly`). `B` processes the message further.

In `A` this looks roughly like this:

```
from(activeMqInQueue)
   .process(/* someBean */)
   .inOnly(/* URI of B */)
.end();
```

Some time later, `B` will make an async call (decoupled by a seda queue) back to `A`. From the perspective of Camel, both calls have nothing to do with each other but from our point, it would be important to acknowledge the message, once we get an answer from `B`. Obviously, we have some form of handler, which can relate the outgoing and incoming call but what we are lacking is the possibility to explicitly acknowledge the original message.

How is this done or what pattern better suits our needs?

Comment: If both calls are async the only way I guess to keep track is probably to use some form of caching to keep track of which requests have been sent to B and which have been acknowledged.

Comment: Hi @SoucianceEqdamRashti, our problem is, that we see no way to manually acknowledge that message (at a moment of our choosing) as the JMSMessage itself is hidden by Camel.  Can we access the message to implement some form of caching?